# Zenscroll doesn't produce smooth scrolling in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue with smooth scroll using vanilla Javascript on Safari browser.
I'm using an event to scroll the webpage to the top when user clicks on the button provided for this purpose.

Smooth scroll works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but this smooth effect doesn't work on Safari and the webpage is scrolled without any effect...

```js
//Zenscroll JS Script

!function(t,e){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define([],e()):"object"==typeof module&&module.exports?module.exports=e():function n(){document&&document.body?t.zenscroll=e():setTimeout(n,9)}()}(this,function(){"use strict";var t=function(t){return t&&"getComputedStyle"in window&&"smooth"===window.getComputedStyle(t)["scroll-behavior"]};if("undefined"==typeof window||!("document"in window))return{};var e=function(e,n,o){n=n||999,o||0===o||(o=9);var i,r=function(t){i=t},u=function(){clearTimeout(i),r(0)},c=function(t){return Math.max(0,e.getTopOf(t)-o)},a=function(o,i,c){if(u(),0===i||i&&i<0||t(e.body))e.toY(o),c&&c();else{var a=e.getY(),f=Math.max(0,o)-a,s=(new Date).getTime();i=i||Math.min(Math.abs(f),n),function t(){r(setTimeout(function(){var n=Math.min(1,((new Date).getTime()-s)/i),o=Math.max(0,Math.floor(a+f*(n<.5?2*n*n:n*(4-2*n)-1)));e.toY(o),n<1&&e.getHeight()+o<e.body.scrollHeight?t():(setTimeout(u,99),c&&c())},9))}()}},f=function(t,e,n){a(c(t),e,n)},s=function(t,n,i){var r=t.getBoundingClientRect().height,u=e.getTopOf(t)+r,s=e.getHeight(),l=e.getY(),d=l+s;c(t)<l||r+o>s?f(t,n,i):u+o>d?a(u-s+o,n,i):i&&i()},l=function(t,n,o,i){a(Math.max(0,e.getTopOf(t)-e.getHeight()/2+(o||t.getBoundingClientRect().height/2)),n,i)};return{setup:function(t,e){return(0===t||t)&&(n=t),(0===e||e)&&(o=e),{defaultDuration:n,edgeOffset:o}},to:f,toY:a,intoView:s,center:l,stop:u,moving:function(){return!!i},getY:e.getY,getTopOf:e.getTopOf}},n=document.documentElement,o=function(){return window.scrollY||n.scrollTop},i=e({body:document.scrollingElement||document.body,toY:function(t){window.scrollTo(0,t)},getY:o,getHeight:function(){return window.innerHeight||n.clientHeight},getTopOf:function(t){return t.getBoundingClientRect().top+o()-n.offsetTop}});if(i.createScroller=function(t,o,i){return e({body:t,toY:function(e){t.scrollTop=e},getY:function(){return t.scrollTop},getHeight:function(){return Math.min(t.clientHeight,window.innerHeight||n.clientHeight)},getTopOf:function(t){return t.offsetTop}},o,i)},"addEventListener"in window&&!window.noZensmooth&&!t(document.body)){var r="history"in window&&"pushState"in history,u=r&&"scrollRestoration"in history;u&&(history.scrollRestoration="auto"),window.addEventListener("load",function(){u&&(setTimeout(function(){history.scrollRestoration="manual"},9),window.addEventListener("popstate",function(t){t.state&&"zenscrollY"in t.state&&i.toY(t.state.zenscrollY)},!1)),window.location.hash&&setTimeout(function(){var t=i.setup().edgeOffset;if(t){var e=document.getElementById(window.location.href.split("#")[1]);if(e){var n=Math.max(0,i.getTopOf(e)-t),o=i.getY()-n;0<=o&&o<9&&window.scrollTo(0,n)}}},9)},!1);var c=new RegExp("(^|\\s)noZensmooth(\\s|$)");window.addEventListener("click",function(t){for(var e=t.target;e&&"A"!==e.tagName;)e=e.parentNode;if(!(!e||1!==t.which||t.shiftKey||t.metaKey||t.ctrlKey||t.altKey)){if(u){var n=history.state&&"object"==typeof history.state?history.state:{};n.zenscrollY=i.getY();try{history.replaceState(n,"")}catch(t){}}var o=e.getAttribute("href")||"";if(0===o.indexOf("#")&&!c.test(e.className)){var a=0,f=document.getElementById(o.substring(1));if("#"!==o){if(!f)return;a=i.getTopOf(f)}t.preventDefault();var s=function(){window.location=o},l=i.setup().edgeOffset;l&&(a=Math.max(0,a-l),r&&(s=function(){history.pushState({},"",o)})),i.toY(a,null,s)}}},!1)}return i});


var arrowElt = document.getElementById("arrow-top");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {

 if (window.pageYOffset < 50) {
  arrowElt.classList.remove("active-arrow");

 } else {
  arrowElt.classList.add("active-arrow");
 }
 
 arrowElt.addEventListener("click", function () {
        // I tried that way at first

  //window.scroll ({
  // top: 0,
  // left: 0,
  // behavior: 'smooth'
  //});

        // Then I tried this way in a second time
        zenscroll.toY(0)
 });
});
```

```css
* {
 list-style: none;
}

body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background: url("../images/background.png") fixed;
 font-family: 'Raleway', 'sans-serif';
}


/* HEADER */

.header > div:nth-child(2) {
 margin: 0;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
}

header > .row {
 height: 80px;
}

.header {
 background-color: #000;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 100000;
 transition: 0.8s;
}

.row > h1,
nav > ul {
 margin: 0;
}

.row > h1 {
 color: #B3A2D5;
 font-size: 30px;
}

.row > h1 > a,
.row > h1 > a:visited {
 color: #B3A2D5;
}

.navb {
 padding: 0;
}

nav > ul {
 padding: 0;
}

nav > p {
 display: none;
 visibility: hidden;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
 display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #B3A2D5;
 font-size: 18px;
}

nav > ul > li > a:visited,
nav > ul > li > a:hover {
 color: #B3A2D5;
}

nav > ul > li:nth-child(2) {
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
}


/* SECTION */

section > h2 {
 font-size: 44px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000;
}

section > p:nth-child(2) {
 font-size: 22px;
 text-align: center;
}

#tumblr-section {
 margin-top: 140px;
}

.jumbotron:last-child > .container-contenu-article > .contenu-article {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 text-align: center;
 align-items: center;
}

#arrow-top {
 background: url("../images/arrow-top.png")center no-repeat;
 height: 45px;
 width: 45px;
 position: fixed;
 right: 35px;
 bottom: 30px;
 opacity: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: 0.6s;
 background-color: #333;
 border-radius: 5px;
 transform: translateX(100px);
 z-index: 100;
}

#arrow-top.active-arrow {
 opacity: 1;
 transition: 0.6s;
 transform: translateX(0);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1220px) {
 section > h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
 }

 section > p:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 16px;

 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {

 body {
  background: url("../images/background.png") no-repeat fixed;
 }

 nav > ul > li > a,
 nav > ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 14px;
 }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 
 .header {
  height: 80px;
 }
 
 .linktitle {
  font-size: 22px;
 }
 
 .infosElts {
  font-size: 14px;
 }

 ul > li {
  visibility: hidden;
 }

    .row > h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
 }

 nav > p {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }

 .toggle-btn {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: 18px;
  left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1000;
 }

 .toggle-btn span {
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  transition: .4s;
 }

 .toggle-btn span:before {
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: 0;
  transition: .4s;
 }

 .toggle-btn span:after {
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
 }

 .menu {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0px;
  width: 230px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.6s;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 505px) {
 section > h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
 }

 section > p:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 14px;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 370px) {

 .toggle-btn {
  left: 0px;
 }
 
 #tumblr-section {
  margin-top: 110px;
 }

 footer img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style-news.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/media-queries-news.css">
 <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
 <header class="container-fluid header">
  <div class="toggle-btn">
   <span></span>
  </div>

  <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">

   <h1 class="col-12 col-md-6 text-center text-md-left pl-0 pl-sm-3"><a href="index.html">TITLE</a></h1>

   <nav class="col-md-6 menu navb text-center">
    <p class="mt-3 menu-nav-mobile">Menu</p>
    <ul class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row text-center justify-content-between">
     <li class="mt-4 mt-md-0 underline-over"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
     <li class="mt-4 mt-md-0">NEWS</li>
     <li class="mt-4 mt-md-0 underline-over"><a href="">BIOGRAPHY</a></li>
     <li class="mt-4 mt-md-0 underline-over"><a href="">DISCOGRAPHY</a></li>
     <li class="mt-4 mt-md-0 underline-over"><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </header>


 <section id="tumblr-section" class="container">
 
  <h2 class="col-12">TUMBLR ARTICLES</h2>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.          Mauris non metus ornare, auctor ipsum ac, pharetra enim.          Integer ut suscipit ex, at rutrum quam. Pellentesque              sodales purus ac massa dignissim, ultrices ultrices leo            feugiat. Donec et porttitor mi. Mauris condimentum purus a        mattis iaculis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur            adipiscing elit. Donec ac dui purus. Donec tincidunt sed          nunc vitae volutpat. Maecenas fermentum orci metus, at            pellentesque orci dapibus non. Aenean est lectus, tincidunt        id enim at, consequat ornare sapien. Aenean accumsan augue        diam, et sagittis est interdum quis. Ut imperdiet quam ac          hendrerit rutrum. Maecenas sit amet porta sapien. Aliquam          erat volutpat. </p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.          Mauris non metus ornare, auctor ipsum ac, pharetra enim.          Integer ut suscipit ex, at rutrum quam. Pellentesque              sodales purus ac massa dignissim, ultrices ultrices leo            feugiat. Donec et porttitor mi. Mauris condimentum purus a        mattis iaculis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur            adipiscing elit. Donec ac dui purus. Donec tincidunt sed          nunc vitae volutpat. Maecenas fermentum orci metus, at            pellentesque orci dapibus non. Aenean est lectus, tincidunt        id enim at, consequat ornare sapien. Aenean accumsan augue        diam, et sagittis est interdum quis. Ut imperdiet quam ac          hendrerit rutrum. Maecenas sit amet porta sapien. Aliquam          erat volutpat. </p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.          Mauris non metus ornare, auctor ipsum ac, pharetra enim.          Integer ut suscipit ex, at rutrum quam. Pellentesque              sodales purus ac massa dignissim, ultrices ultrices leo            feugiat. Donec et porttitor mi. Mauris condimentum purus a        mattis iaculis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur            adipiscing elit. Donec ac dui purus. Donec tincidunt sed          nunc vitae volutpat. Maecenas fermentum orci metus, at            pellentesque orci dapibus non. Aenean est lectus, tincidunt        id enim at, consequat ornare sapien. Aenean accumsan augue        diam, et sagittis est interdum quis. Ut imperdiet quam ac          hendrerit rutrum. Maecenas sit amet porta sapien. Aliquam          erat volutpat. </p>
  
  <span id="arrow-top"></span>
  
 </section>
  </body>
  
 </html>
```

I know window.scroll ({ top:0, left:0, "behavior": "smooth" }) is not supported by Safari, but I also tried Zenscroll Javascript Module (https://github.com/zengabor/zenscroll), which is supposed to work on Safari, but I still have the same issue...

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Why don't you replace this: `<span id="arrow-top"></span>` with this: `<a href="#" id="arrow-top"></a>`

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: Ensure window.noZensmooth = false, 
consider using zenscroll.createScroller(body, null, 20) for manually creating a scroller on body
try changing position of body/html https://github.com/zengabor/zenscroll#7-scroll-inside-a-scrollable-div

Answer (score 1):

ZenScroll works for me on Safari, I'm running the latest version as of 2021 (MacBook Air M1 Chip, Big Sur). Did you add the following script to the bottom of the html body?

```html
  <script src="./assets/javascript/zenscroll-min.js"></script>
</body>
```